# c# SelectSingleNode in xml returns null. There is no similar resolutions this issue at this site

Tags: c#, xml

I've got the problem with reading XML string.
Here I've got the following one:

```xml
<SplitterLayoutDataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/SplitterLayoutDataSet.xsd"> 
    <SplitterLayout> 
        <SplitterName>mainSplitContainerControl</SplitterName> 
            <SplitterPosition>0.2213375796178344</SplitterPosition> 
     </SplitterLayout> 
</SplitterLayoutDataSet>
```

So, I want to read `<SplitterName>` tag wih the following code:

```
XmlElement rootElement = doc.DocumentElement;
rootElement.RemoveAllAttributes();
if (rootElement != null)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Control, object> key in SaveLayoutControls)
        {
            Control c = key.Key;
            XmlElement el = rootElement.SelectSingleNode("SplitterName") as XmlElement;
            if (el != null)
            {
                if (c is GridControl)
                    SetGridLayout(el, c as GridControl);
                else if (c is SplitContainerControl)
                    SetSplitContainerLayout(el, c as SplitContainerControl);
                else if (c is TreeList)
                    SetTreeListLayout(el, c as TreeList);
                else if (c is CollapsibleSplitter)
                    SetCollapsibleSplitterLayout(el, c as CollapsibleSplitter);
                else if (c is Splitter)
                    SetSplitterLayout(el, c as Splitter);
                }
            }
       }
```

I want to read the "el" field, but it returns me NULL value. Are there any ideas to resolve this issue? Because I tried many ways and had no result. Thanks

Comment: Try  <SplitterName> instead of  SplitterName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1) You're asking for a `SplitterName` element *without a namespace* whereas the one in your XML file implicitly uses the namespace URI `"http://tempuri.org/SplitterLayoutDataSet.xsd"`.

2) You're asking for a node directly under the document element, and your `SplitterName` element *isn't* a direct child of `SplitterLayoutDataSet`.

You definitely *can* use XPath for this using [`XmlNamespaceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx), but personally I'd try to use LINQ to XML:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://tempuri.org/SplitterLayoutDataSet.xsd";
XElement root = ...;
XElement names = root.Descendants(ns + "SplitterName").First();
```

(Additionally, it's not clear why you're searching for that element on every iteration, when you're not using `key` anywhere in the search...)

Comment: Beat me to it! Nice answer.

Comment: I tried to use such way, but the row "XElement names = root.Descendants(ns + "SplitterName");" returns a casting error. Also, there are compilation errors after "if (el != null)". You told there were abilities to use XmlNamespaceManager. Are there any hints to resolve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kirill: Sorry, fixed that bit to find the first descendant. You should adjust it if you want to find others. As for the compilation errors - given that we don't know what those errors are, or what `SetGridLayout` is, etc, it's hard to help more. For XmlNamespaceManager, just search - there are plenty of examples around.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Sorry for lack of information, I'll try to redo that fix and provide you more info

Comment: @Kirill: To be honest, once you've got the information out of the XML element, that should be the end of this question. If you've got another question about how to *use* that information, it would be better to ask it in a separate question IMO.

Comment: Ok, here is a compilation error info, for example: The best overloaded method match for 'SetGridLayout(System.Xml.XmlElement, DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl)' has some invalid arguments for method SetGridLayout(el, c as GridControl); because the signature of this method takes the firs argument as XmlElement. Are there any ideas to cast this argument or something like this? Thanks. UPD: root.Descendants now works OK :)

Comment: @Kirill: I have no idea where SetGridLayout comes from. Is it your own method? Is it a DevExpress one? I think you need to do some more digging for yourself, then ask another question.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I found the solution, it's in my answer. The main problem was getting null value at XmlElement el

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath doesn't point to the right place.

"SplitterName" xpath would check for that element under the root element.

Use

"//SplitterName" or "//SplitterLayout/SplitterName" or "\SplitterLayoutDataSet/SplitterLayout/SplitterName"

AND remove the xmlns="zzz" or add NamespaceManager to the query with the namespace added and the XPath elements prefixed, such as "//ns:SplitterName"

Comment: I believe XPath uses forward slashes rather than backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution. I tried to use namespaces, now this part of code works OK. Here is the following sample of code;

```cs
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.InnerXml = xml;
    XmlElement rootElement = doc.DocumentElement as XmlElement;
    XmlNamespaceManager xns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    xns.AddNamespace("ns", "http://tempuri.org/SplitterLayoutDataSet.xsd");
    if (rootElement != null)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Control, object> key in SaveLayoutControls)
        {
            Control c = key.Key;
            XmlElement el = rootElement.SelectSingleNode("ns:SplitterLayout", xns) as XmlElement;
            if (el != null)
            {
                if (c is GridControl)
                    SetGridLayout(el, c as GridControl);
                else if (c is SplitContainerControl)
                    SetSplitContainerLayout(el, c as SplitContainerControl);
                else if (c is TreeList)
                    SetTreeListLayout(el, c as TreeList);
                else if (c is CollapsibleSplitter)
                    SetCollapsibleSplitterLayout(el, c as CollapsibleSplitter);
                else if (c is Splitter)
                    SetSplitterLayout(el, c as Splitter);
            }
        }
    }
```